# Inverses of two argument functions with respect to one argument

Tags: general-topology, functions, terminology, inverse

Consider a function $f : A \times B \to C$ and two inverses, each with respect to one argument; i.e. $g$ and $h$ defined such that $f(x,y)=z \iff g(y,z)=x \iff h(z,x)=y$. A simple example is addition:

$$
f(x,y) = x+y \\
g(y,z) = z-y \\
h(z,x) = z-x
$$

Such collections can of course be generalized to any number of arguments.

Is there a name for $g$ and $h$? (It's not "partial inverse," though that would be a great name for them, analogous to "partial derivative.")

I believe they exist if $f$ is continuous, surjective, and monotone in each argument. Under what other conditions do they exist?

In general, what search terms should I use to find properties about them?

Comment: Should this get moved to mathoverflow.net?

Comment: Asked at mathoverflow.net (http://mathoverflow.net/questions/145676/inverses-of-two-argument-functions-with-respect-to-one-argument)